# Can't capture groups in a string using REGEX

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match strings of the following format:

```
S->A  
S->AbCd  
S->A|b|C|d  
S->Ab|B|cde|dB
```

That is, on the leftmost side there is exactly one capital latin alphabet symbol followed by '->' literal. After that literal follows exactly one capital/non-capital latin alphabet symbol or a concatenation of such symbols that can also be followed by such groups of symbol(s) delimited by the '|' symbol.
Also I want not only to check whether the whole string adheres to this format but also be able to capture both the leftmost capital symbol and all symbol groups after the '->' literal. So far I have come up with this regex:

```
([A-Z]{1})->([a-zA-Z]+)(?:(?:\|)([a-zA-Z]+))*
```

If I test it against, for example, this string:

```
S->Ab|B|c|d
```

I get the following results (testing done with RegexBuddy):

```
Match 1:    S->Ab|B|c|d
Group 1:    S
Group 2:    Ab
Group 3:    d
```

The good thing is that my regex matches the whole string (which is correct). The problem however is obvious: my regex captures only the first and last symbol group after the '->' literal. Why? Based on my understanding of regexes this part of the expression

```
(?:(?:\|)([a-zA-Z]+))*
```

should match **ALL** delimited symbol groups. I believe it's something related to what's described in the article ['Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group'](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html). I have tried to fiddle around with my regex a little but still got no satisfying results. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which language is hosting the regex?

Comment: If the leftmost has to be a capital latin letter, you should remove the [a-z] - part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your problem is, you are repeating a capturing group.

```
(?:(?:\|)([a-zA-Z]+))*
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
          third group
```

You are right, this whole part is matching all of your repeating groups and each of those matches is stored in `$3`, so as result after all matching is done, you can only see the last match of this group, which is `d` in your example.

You can capture your repeated group like this

```
([a-zA-Z]{1})->([a-zA-Z]+)((?:(?:\|)[a-zA-Z]+)*)
```

Then your result would look like this

```
Match 1:    S->Ab|B|c|d
Group 1:    S
Group 2:    Ab
Group 3:    |B|c|d
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips.
However do I understand it correctly that there is no way to write regex that would produce a separate group for all matching items prefixed by '|'?

Comment: Which language are you using? Most are not, but I think .net is able to do it (and I heard Perl 6).

Answer (score 2):

There are only three pairs of capturing parentheses in the regex, so you can only get three groups out (and it is related 'capturing a repeated group versus repeating a capturing group').  The number of groups is always fixed.

Using Perl-like spacing `m//x` to split things up for clarity:

```
([a-zA-Z]{1})  ->  ([a-zA-Z]+)  (?: (?:\|) ([a-zA-Z]+) )*
^-----------^      ^---------^             ^---------^
```

The three capturing parts are shown.  The other parentheses are non-capturing.  Obviously, you can capture the whole of the trailing group:

```
    ([a-zA-Z]{1})  ->  ([a-zA-Z]+)  ( (?:\|) (?:[a-zA-Z]+) )*
```

but then you need to post-process the trailing group, perhaps with a `split` operation, to get the sub-fields.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `(?:...)` means a **non-capturing** group.

If you want a **capturing** group you should use `(...)` instead.

Try this:

```
([a-zA-Z]{1})->([a-zA-Z]+)(\|[a-zA-Z]+)*
```

If you want each element separately you can split on the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

the capturing group 3 matches all symbols `([a-zA-Z]+)` - it will first match "B", then it is replaced by "c" as the regex progresses after the next `|` and finally it is replaced by "d" as in your result..